# Nextjs - getInitialProps make reload and delete store

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch, server-side, next.js

I built a site with `nextjs` (with server express & API) and `Reactjs`.

I would like to create dynamic paginations because there is far too much result for statically generated, So I added server endpoint **/publiations/page/:id**, I put a `getInitialsProps` for keep the id in query

But actually, when I click on my main page /publications where my store is not empty to go to the next page (**publications/page/1**), the page reloads and the store is empty. How I can keep my store when I change route?

And here my **publications/page/[id].js**

```
const PublicationsPage = ({id}) => {
  return (
      <>
        <MainMenu/>
        <Search/>
        <div className="flex">
          <Sidebar fallback={<Loader/>}/>
          <Cards type={'publications'} idPage={id} />
        </div>
      </>
  )
}


PublicationsPage.getInitialProps = async function({ query: { id } }) {
  return {
    id: id
  };
};

export default withAuthSync(PublicationsPage);
```

The cards components where i use the data of store :
components/Cards.js

```
const Cards = ({ idPage, cards, type }) => {

  console.log(cards)

    return (
        <div className="cards">
            <div className="content-filter-search">
                <div className="content-newsearchresult">
                    <div className="global-name">Result: {cards.cards.length} articles found</div>
                    <div className="content-button-blue">
                        <Link href="/explorer">
                            <a>
                                <div className="button-blue">New search</div>
                            </a>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="content-filter">
                    {filters[idPage].map((item) => {
                        return <InputFilter key={item.id} data={item} callback={keepItems} />;
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="wrapper-card">
                <div className="cards-container">
        {
          !cards.loading ? cards.cards.slice(idPage * 9, idPage * 9 + 9).map((card) => (
            <Card key={card.PMCID}  data={card} />
          )) : <Spinner color="black" size="100px" thickness={3} gap={5} speed="fast" />
        }
                </div>
            </div>
      <div className="text">
        <Link href={'/publications/page/1'}><a>Next page</a></Link>
      </div>
      {
        !cards.loading ? (
          <div className="center">
                    <Pagination type={type} page={parseInt(idPage)} totalElement={cards.cards.length} numberPerPage={9} />
                </div>
        ) : null
      }
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  cards: state.cards,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Cards);
```

I use the same code for the route **/publications** and **/publications/page/:id** just I add the getInitialProps to keep the id of page. And I use connect redux in my Cards component

I have no error in the console just my store is reset because the page reload. I don't understand how I can make pagination with my store where is my data if when I change page the store is empty

Thanks

Comment: You mean when you render (ssr) your publications page you dispatch some data in store which you lose the same data when you render(ssr) /publications/page/:id ? Is this your problem ?

Comment: Could you please share your publications/page.js ?

Comment: yes exactly, i have juste publications/index.js and publications/page/:id

Comment: Have you figured it out ?